# Android make download manager download files one at a time?

Tags: android, download, android-progressbar, android-download-manager, simultaneous

I have a `ListView` populated by items. These items represent files I can download by clicking on them. When I click on an item, the `download manager` is launched and downloads the file in a directory I created.

While a file is being downloaded, an indeterminate `progress bar` ( loading wheel ) is made visible on the corresponding item in the list.

My problem is : since I recognize the loading wheels (to hide them) by when their item has been clicked on (first item clicked, second item clicked, fifth item clicked etc...), I don't want the `download manager` to download multiple files simultaneously.

e.g. : if I click on a big file and then on a small file in the list, I want the big file to be completely downloaded before begining to download the small one.

Is there a way to do this ?

**EDIT :** Here is my code

`y`,`z`, and `ld` are set to `0` at the begining.

When an item is being clicked :

```
// Loader of the clicked item is made visible
loader[z].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Construction of the URL
SharedPreferences codeSaveUrl = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_TEXT,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
url2 = codeSaveUrl.getString("defaut", ""); // Organization code
uri = url10 + url2 + "&file=" + udl ;

// URL parse to URI
Uri myuri = Uri.parse(uri);

// Enqueue file to downloads, with notification. Storage of download id in a table
lastDownload[ld] = mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(myuri)
.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
.setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
.setTitle(udl + ".pdf")
.setDescription("Téléchargement en cours")
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Protocols/", (udl+".pdf"))
.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE));

// Increment variables for next downloads
ld=ld+1;
z=z+1;
```

Broadcast Receiver :

```
// Broadcast Receiver called when a download is finished
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // referenceId is the download's id for which the method is called
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        // If y (=0 at the beginning) is inferior to the number of downloads
        if(y <ld){
            // If the id of the download corresponds to the one for which the method is called
            if(lastDownload[y] == referenceId){
                // We define a cursor depending on the id
                Cursor c = mgr.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(lastDownload[y]));
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    // Download status recovery
                    int x = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                    switch(x){
                    // If download is paused, pending or running, we do nothing
                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                        break;
                    // If file has successfully been downloaded, loader is hidden
                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                        loader[y].setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                        // Increment y to go to next download
                        y=y+1;
                        break;
                    // If download failed, it is retried
                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                        //TODO: retry download
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find how to download files one at a time, but I found a way to resolve my problem.

Here is another question I posted, with my own answer : [Android progressbar in listview while using downloadmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447395/android-progressbar-in-listview-while-using-downloadmanager)